# Best way to fill in a PHP/HTML form with user specific mysql saved data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Question: How do I get a PHP/HTML form to fill back in with previously submitted user data found in the mysql database?

Okay, I've been browsing the internet for a couple of weeks now trying to find a tutorial or some thread out there that can help me with this.

I'm creating a web form for a tabletop RPG game.  It is a simple form that has mostly fields and drop down menus with things like 'Character Name', 'Age', 'Gender', etc.

- I have gotten it to where it will save to the mysql database.
- I also have it so that their is a foreign key to link the data to the
  user logged in.
- Now, I have a: $_REQUEST['Character'] (Character is the name of the
  form) that allows all the inputted data to be in the corresponding
  boxes after a submission in case of errors or the like (with the
  exception of the drop down menus staying on the selected items, which
  I'm reading about right now).

But now I want it so that if the user has already created a character, when they log back in, all that information will be pulled back and filled into the form in the appropriate fields.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?  Or could anyone point me in the right direction of another answered thread, video, what have you, that would better explain this to me?

*I didn't think any code would be required for you all to look at but I can post some code if need be, there is just a lot of it*

Comment: Take the array you get back from the database, and stick it in `$_REQUEST['Character']`...?  That'd be the simplest way, if you have forms that remember the values posted so far...just pretend the row was a posted form.  (This assumes you're not doing a lot of mangling of the data on its way into the database.  If you do, you're going to have to massage it back into form-post form.)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about trying to get the array to fill in. All the 'tutorials' I have seen in regards to the array generally go about having it take the array and then just printing the values out, not filling in a form/table. I'll give that a shot.

And the values for the fields are just what each field is called, like Character Name is 'CharacterName', would I need more than that in the value field to fill everything in?

Comment: If you put `$_REQUEST['Character']['CharacterName']` into a field named `CharacterName`, it might be that simple.  If the field name is different, you might use column aliases to make the column names match the form field names.  But i usually prefer to have the form field names match the column names, which makes it almost trivial to grab a DB row and use it as a form data set.

Comment: Well, I tried writing it like this: value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['Character']['CharacterName']; ?> in the tag for the Character Name but it didn't do anything.  I think I'm just being way more complicated at this than I should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simple example.  Let's say we have a table `Characters`, with fields `id`, `name` and `age`.

One of the cleaner ways (IMO) to provide an edit form for this table, is to have the form assume there's an array (let's call it `$char`) that has these fields.  The main code would get this array from wherever, be it from the form fields or from the database.

(Note, a lot of stuff has been omitted.  I don't know or care what database you're using, or how you do validation; the important part is the form processing, and that works regardless of DB.)

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="Character[id]" value="<?= intval($char['id']) ?>">
 <input name="Character[name]" value="<?= htmlentities($char['name']) ?>">
 <input name="Character[age]" value="<?= htmlentities($char['age']) ?>">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, `$_POST['Character']` would be an array, and contains all the info the form submitted about the character.

Let's have a `saveCharacter` that would take that info and save it as a row...
(pseudocode lines start with `...`; fragments look `...like this...`)

```
function saveCharacter($char) {
    if (empty($char['id'])):
        ... do insert
        ... $char['id'] = last insert ID
    else:
        ... do update
    endif;

    // return the saved char; inserting would have added an ID
    return $char;
}
```

...and a `loadCharacter` to SELECT that row, and return its contents with the same names as you had them in the form.  (Keeping the form and database field names consistent helps quite a bit here.  If the two use the same names, you can just return the row directly.)

```
function loadCharacter($id) {
    ... $result = result from: SELECT id, name, age FROM Characters WHERE id = ?
    ... return first (should be only) row of $result
}
```

(If the names are different, you'll need to convert.  You can usually have the DBMS do this for you; google for "SQL column alias" for more info.)

And the code to kick all this off...

```
if (isset($_POST['Character'])) {
    $char = saveCharacter($_POST['Character']);
}
elseif ( ...the user already has a character id... ) {
    $char = loadCharacter(...character id...);
}
else {
    // first time on the page, and there's no saved character
    // give $char the right field names, to prevent notices
    $char = array('id' => null, 'name' => null, 'age' => null);
}
```

And when you include the form from above, it will put `$char`'s values in the proper elements.